# passing on value from geolocation to local method fails

Tags: angular

I would like to get the user's current location and send it to a webservice, to get the current weather for that location.

I'm injecting my service in the constructor of my Component.

```
  constructor(private owmService: OwmService) {
  }
```

Get the location:

```
  ngOnInit() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
        console.log("getCurrentPosition succesful", position); //I see the value of position, it's fine.
        this.getCurrentWeatherViaPosition(position); //this fails to pass on the value :(
      });
    }
  }
```

Error message:
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'getCurrentWeatherViaPosition' of null

I want to pass on the position to this method:

```
 getCurrentWeatherViaPosition(position: Position): void {
    this.owmService.getCurrentWeatherViaPosition(position)
      .subscribe((currentWeather: CurrentWeather) => {
        //got response from API
      });
  }
```

What am I doing wrong? How I'm supposed to pass on the value from the (async?) geolocation call to my local private method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use

```
function () {...}
```

`this` will point to `geoLocation`.

Use arrow functions instead

```
 navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((position) => {
```

then `this` will point to the class instance where this code is.